# Ask a makefile to print a variable value

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have some generated GNUmakefiles from which I need to extract the value of a variable.

Is there an easy way to see the value of a variable without modifying the makefiles ?

FYI, the variables contain the path of some include files necessary for the emacs c-macro-expand function.

Comment: Why *without modifying the makefiles*?

Comment: I work in a MegaCorp where it's difficult to modify anything. The makefiles are generated, I would have to modify the engine which create makefiles, and that seems very difficult.

Comment: You have my sympathy. MegaCorps and code generators have the same fault: layers of inflexible heirarchy that make change difficult.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create a wrapper makefile, which includes necessary GNUmakefiles and prints the variable. For example, create `wrapper.mk` with the content

```
include GNUmakefile

$(info $(value VAR_NAME))
```

and then invoke Make with `-n` flag (see @jeberle's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14164367/545027)):

```
make -f wrapper.mk -n  # will print the variable value to stdout
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
$ make -n -p | grep VAR
```

to pick out the value

the flags are:

```
-n  # don't really make
-p  # print database
```

Comment: It does not evaluate the value of the variables, so it prints something like : `INCFLAGS=$(MYINCFLAGS) -I...`

Comment: You can grep for any name, e.g., `grep MYINCFLAGS`. If `MYINCFLAGS` is not set, it will evaluate to an empty string.