# How to discover default target in make?

Tags: gnu-make

I've seen the question ["How does “make” app know default target to build if no target is specified?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2057689/8446), which explains that the default target is the first target that doesn't being with a '.'.

How do I get make to **tell** me what that target is?

Context: I've got a recursive make system, with a variety of included makefiles. If I add a new target to my top level Makefile (or to my common include), that becomes the default target. I want to add `.DEFAULT_GOAL: original-default-target`, but I don't know what `original-default-target` *is*.

Answer (score 3):

Running `make -d` results in a *lot* of debug output. If you search this for the first occurrence of 'Updating goal targets', and look at the next target mentioned, this appears to be the default target.

For example:

```
$ make -d | grep -A2 -m1 'goal targets'
Updating goal targets....
Considering target file 'all'.
 File 'all' does not exist.
```

This implies that, for this Makefile at least, the current default target is `all`. This can then be enforced by adding `.DEFAULT_GOAL: all` to the top-level Makefile.

Answer (score 1):

A reliable way, which doesn't depend on parsing debug output (which is not documented, thus subject to change) is to run make in `--query` and `--print-database` modes together, then grep for the `.DEFAULT_GOAL` assignment. This variable, along with some examples and other special variables, is documented at [Special Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Variables.html).

```bash
make -qp | grep ^".DEFAULT_GOAL := " | tail -n 1
```

Since `--query` + `--print-database` mode does not try to make (not even resolve dependencies and file freshness), it has two advantages compared with Roger's answer:

1. no recipes are run
2. directories are not recursed, no sub-makes are spawned. You get the `.DEFAULT_GOAL` of the current directory's Makefile

The `tail -n 1` bit is needed to reliably get correct output. The output of  something like `$(info .DEFAULT_GOAL := fake-goal)` in the makefile is sent to stdout first. The variables and rules are printed last, after the makefile is fully parsed and variables expanded. Hence, the last instance of `.DEFAULT_GOAL` on stdout is the genuine one you're looking for.

**Caution:** A makefile is effectively a script executed on parse, whether in `--query`/`--dry-run` mode or not. Functions are expanded, so something like `$(shell BOOM)` is expanded before at makefile parse time. It's not possible to reliably parse a makefile and determine the default target without executing anything. **Only run `make` on makefiles you trust, or sandbox it.**

Related questions:

- [Ask a makefile to print a variable value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14163969/ask-a-makefile-to-print-a-variable-value)
- [Makefile DEFAULT_GOAL variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28299370/makefile-default-goal-variable)